# RuntimeError: Remote tunnel helper is unaware of

Tags: cloud-foundry

Trying to tunnel into mongodb using vmc and I see the following error

```
vmc tunnel
1: mongodb-XY
2: redis-XY
Which service instance?> 1

1: none
2: mongorestore
3: mongo
4: mongodump
Which client would you like to start?> 3

Opening tunnel on port 10000... FAILED
RuntimeError: Remote tunnel helper is unaware of mongodb-XY!
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash
```

Here is the error log..
cat ~/.vmc/crash

```
Time of crash:
  Tue Jan 01 23:09:58 -0600 2013

RuntimeError: Remote tunnel helper is unaware of mongodb-XY!

tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.1.10/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:233:in `get_connection_info'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.1.10/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:35:in `open!'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.1.10/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:41:in `tunnel'
interact-0.5.1/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.1.10/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:40:in `tunnel'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `send'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `run'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in `execute'
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:11
/usr/bin/vmc:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/vmc:19
```

--

The service is running and so is the app that is using the service. Any ideas?

vmc services

```
Getting services... OK

name           service   version
mongodb-XY   mongodb   2.0    
redis-XY     redis     2.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do when you see this error is to remove the caldecott application and try the tunnel again. To remove caldecott, just do;

```
vmc delete caldecott
```